# Find Cursor position from left and top in pixels

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, javascript-objects, document

I am trying to find the cursor left,top position in textarea relevant to whole document. This text area can be placed anywhere on the page. I want to know the exact position of cursor from the left and from the top of the whole document.

I have tried some code

```
<div id="db" style="position:absolute;left:-20px;top:-20px;border:1px solid red;">V</div>
<br><br><br>
<form id="props">
    <textarea id="ta" style="width:200px;height:100px;" onkeyup="moveDiv();"></textarea>
</form>
```

JS

```
var b=document.body;
var d=document.getElementById('db');
var a=document.getElementById('ta');

function moveDiv(){
    var sel = document.getSelection();
    var targ = sel.getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer;

    d.style.top=a.offsetTop+a.clientTop-d.clientHeight-6;
    d.style.left = targ.offsetLeft + b.scrollLeft - 6;
    return;
}
```

But it's not working.

please help!
thanks

Comment: Your function moveDiv() is not getting called..check that first then expect your code to either work or throw errors

Comment: @Krishna9960: it is called onkeyup.

Comment: Check your code on this fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/8397/

For me its not triggering on key up..you get an error function not defined

Comment: @Krishna9960: I don't know why Fiddle stucks on it... But it triggers on [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/MoyqzN?editors=1111)

Comment: @guys. It works now in fiddle. The Jquery UI was not included.

Comment: @Abhishek: I don't think you can get the cursor position in pixel precisely. You'll have to do complex calculations to evaluate the average character width and estimate the position... And I don't talk about cursor beeing on second line of the textarea yet...

Comment: @Rushit: ? That is only JavaScript...

Comment: I tried https://github.com/beviz/jquery-caret-position-getter works fine with textarea. But not with richtexteditors :(